# substring dynamic number of characters

Tags: mysql, substring

I'm working with 2 sets of data that were merged together, but they're inconsistent in their format. Some are 10 characters, all numbers. Others may have a separator `:` at position 4. I need to substring the first 4 characters. But if the 4th character is a `:` substring only the first 3 characters.

Does mysql have an `IF` functionality to determine the number of characters to substring based on the character in position 4?

```
select substring(id, 1 , 3/4) from table1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the field like it's colon separated and do this to select only the first part:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, ':', 1)
```

See also: [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided to select the first 4 chars, and just do a trim in case it contains the `:`. Sounds like it might be easier in this case.